# integrating mautic with a custom sms API

Tags: python, sms, mautic

I am trying to integrate a custom SMS API with Mautic. But the problem is that I don't know how to do it using webhooks. I appreciate it if you share your ideas on how to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may need to create an SMS Transport layer, for reference check the twilio plugin and its configuration document. Once you understand it, you should try to create a custom plugin which provides a transport layer over mautic for your custom API.

please refer to official developer documentation https://developer.mautic.org/#plugins

https://tutorialsjoint.com/mautic-plugin-tutorial-directory-structure/

https://tutorialsjoint.com/plugin-tutorial-mvc/

here is another example plugin you can refer https://github.com/acquia/mc-cs-plugin-slooce